# how to get the value of a check box from another list

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, administration

I've been trying to get the value of a check box in a sp list. so, I have List[a] and List[b]. List[b] contains a check box which I am trying to get the value of inorder to put in in List[a].

I'm using Infopath 2010. I've tried doing this by using a ckbox in List[a] -- that did not work. Then tried to use a text box in List[a] to get the value -- that did not work.

Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: "List[b] contains a check box"?! Really list contains data fields and list items (rows). Checkbox is visual control rendering  Yes/No type of data field value in web page or IP form. There are many of them (either Yes/No values or checkboxes) in each of lists! Which of them from  List[b] you want in an item of List[a] ? What is the relationship between 2 Yes/No data fields, or values sets, of 2 lists?

Comment: I'm pulling the list values through a data connection in infopath. the value is (yes/no)

Comment: This is the question! which of the values of a column (of checkboxes of List[b]) to put in one checkbox (or text box) of List[a] item? They are many to choose from and it is not clear how. They are already stored in List[b]

Comment: ??? not sure I understand what you are saying.... there is a check box field that I have in list[b] the values are either yes or no. I'm trying to get that value and put it in list [a] ... "many to choose from " not sure what you are talking about.. there is only one field in the list that is a check box....

Comment: From where do you want to get and use the value, from within InfoPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out. I was choosing my field from the queryFields section instead of the dataFields section. This fixed the issue. Hope this helps someone else too.**

[image: remember to choose the field from the datFields Area]